# How to add a bar that divide yticks into few categories and provide labels of those categories in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

A bar left of the y axis that is divided into few color corresponding to the categories and left to that bar category names. A sample image is attached.
How should I approach this problem?
[image]

Comment: "I want" is probably not the right way to ask for help on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Your question is too broad. There is no code, no data, no attempt, nothing in your question. Providing a solution to such a question would require writing a code from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way. This is by using two axes.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.arange(0,100,2)

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[1].plot(x,x**2)

ax[0].axis('off')
#add text
ax[0].text(0.3,8000,'High',dict(color='red',fontsize=12))
ax[0].text(0.3,4999,'Medium',dict(color='green',fontsize=12))
ax[0].text(0.3,1666,'Low',dict(color='blue',fontsize=12))
#add bar
ax[0].axvspan(.75, .9, ymin=0, ymax=0.33, alpha=0.5, color='blue')
ax[0].axvspan(.75, .9, ymin=0.33, ymax=0.66, alpha=0.5, color='green')
ax[0].axvspan(.75, .9, ymin=0.66, ymax=0.99, alpha=0.5, color='red')

ax[0].set_ylim(ax[1].get_ylim())
ax[0].set_xlim((0,1))
plt.show()
```

[image]